# Making a one to many relationship on one table GRAILS

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have the parent domain of Teacher and child domain of Student ( one to many)

Student have entity of student_certificate which is a byte( upload file to be exact)

my concern here is i want to separate the student_certificate and create another domain of Student_attachment, but the twist i want to do is to lies the student_attachment on the table of Student

is it possible to do?because there is an existing data so creating another table is a risky way

Comment: I would actually suggest this by MANY-TO-MANY. 'Childran has many Teacher and Teacher has many Children

Answer (score 1):

> ...but the twist i want to do is to lies the student_attachment on the
>   table of Student

You can use the `embedded` attribute as shown below:

```
class Teacher {
    String name
    static hasMany = [students: Student]
}

class Student {
    String name
    StudentAttachment certificate
    static embedded = ['certificate']
}

class StudentAttachment {
    byte[] attachment
}


create table student (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, name varchar(255) not null, certificate_attachment binary(255) not null, primary key (id));
create table teacher (id bigint generated by default as identity, version bigint not null, name varchar(255) not null, primary key (id));
create table teacher_student (teacher_students_id bigint not null, student_id bigint);
```

Comment: how about i have an existing column of uploadfile should i rename it to the newly created domain?

Comment: You could rename the column or rename the properties in your model or leave them both as they are and alter the mapping to manage the difference.

Comment: then i can go certificate lazy: true?